# IntelliJ Cant Find Test Context

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I am having issues running unit tests in intelliJ. I have looked through other forums where people have had similar issues but so far I still haven't been able to get it to work. This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/d1/d2/service/ServiceTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

In my test I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "ServiceTest-context.xml")
public class ServiceImplTest ....
```

I have obviously verified that the file exists where it is looking for it in the caused by line. I also read a suggestion to check the output directory and I have verified that it exists there as well. Is there anything else that stands out to you? I can run the tests from the command line using ant but I would like to be able to run individual classes rather than modules.

Project:

```
IntelliJ_project
    src
    test
        com
            d1
                d2
                    otherStuff
                    ...
                    ...
                    service
                        ServiceImplTest.java
                        ServiceTest-context.xml
```

outputFolder:

```
test-classes (output folder)
    com
        d1
            d2
                service
                    ServiceImplTest.class
```

So it turns out I was looking in the wrong directory for the output. The context file does not make it to the output location. How do I get it there?

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Add file tree with Test class source and ServiceTest-context.xml from project root.

Comment: Is this a Maven project? IntelliJ Idea uses `out` directory for native Idea projects (and copies resources itself) and name `test-classes` is a conventional name used by Maven project.

Comment: Yes it is a maven project. According to my co workers though, it works just fine with eclipse.

Comment: If it's a maven project the test sources should reside in test/java and the xml file used should reside in test/resources, as per the standard maven layout. Resources in a maven project will get copied to the output directory automatically by IntelliJ.

Comment: Surely there is a way around it right?

Comment: The workaround is to manually specify your resources in your source test folder in your project's pom (See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)). There is no reason to not adhere to the maven conventions though, because it sounds to me that your build won't even run outside of eclipse, does it?

Comment: Does execution of Maven succeed if you run `mvn clean test` outside of Eclipse? Do you have `testResources` sections in your `pom.xml`? It seems as if Apache Ant or Eclipse project was not fully converted to a Maven project and tests relies on Eclipse side effect of copying resources from source directory.

Comment: I couldn't even get the tests to run inside eclipse but apparently other people can... I have only been at this job like a month so I'm still trying to tread carefully. I was hoping I could just change something in my intellij settings and make it work. Too bad.

Answer (score 6):

If this is a multi-module project and your tests do work when run with

```
mvn test
```

but config file can't be found by IDEA, try this:

1. menu: Run -> Edit Configurations...
2. change "Working Directory" to point at your "Intellij_Project" folder (with a trailing slash).
3. in test class, change your configuration to:

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration("file:test/com/d1/d2/service/ServiceTest-context.xml")
   ```

This configuration worked for me (and is also used by spring-mvc-showcase).

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution, it works for me:

1. Put `ServiceTest-context.xml` into the `src/test/resources` folder.
2. Add these lines to the `build` section of your pom:

   ```
   <testResources>
     <testResource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
     </testResource>
   </testResources>
   ```
3. Reimport Maven project and run your individual tests.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. There appears to be a bug in IntelliJ where it does not copy all files to the target dir. Hence, your context is not found. Had the same issue.

If you check your target/test-classes folder, you may notice the context is not in the desired place. At least that's what I had.

I had lotsa troubles in the past getting it right (besides a manual copy). If you're lucky, try unmarking the test resources and remark it as test resource. Then do a mvn clean. Then run your test. Also, make sure in your test case config, it triggers a Make... That got my context in the test classes. Also verify if the Working directory of your test class is correct. I had a case where it was set to the dir in which I kept the project files....